# 'Waiting for SSH to be available' during creation of a generic docker machine with amazon aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-machine

I'm trying to use docker-machine with my docker instance hosted on amazon aws.

I run the following command:

```
$ sudo docker-machine create --driver generic --generic-ip-address={EC2 IP} --generic-ssh-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa dockeraws
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(dockering) Importing SSH key...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Error creating machine: Error detecting OS: Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded
```

But It stucks on 'Waiting for SSH to be available...' and I don't know why.

I've also opened the ports '22' and '2376' but it's still not working.

For my instance I'm using the template stated on the docker page here -> https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/

Comment: Are you able to ssh manually? `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ${EC2_USER}@${EC2_IP}`? Do you need to pass `--generic-ssh-user`?

Comment: @leodotcloud Found out that manually it's also not working. For ssh access I'm using a '.pem' file instead of '~/.ssh/id_rsa' but if I add the pem file to the command it automatically add's a .pub at the end of the file and so the cli can not find the file because it's only '.pem' and not '.pem.pub'.

Comment: Syntax: ssh -i ~/.ssh/some-private-key.pem ${EC2_USER}@${EC2_IP} if executed from command line should not append pub to key name. Can you double check that private key file is indeed properly named with proper permission?

Comment: @Const No the connection with ssh works. If I add the pem-file to the 'docker-machine create' command it add's a '.pub' ending.

Comment: This is similar when creating keypair, and seems like same assumptions are made there. Can you rename your private key to be without extension (say my-key.pem to my-key)  and private to be same name with pub extension (my-key.pub) and then reference only name (my-key) when starting?

Comment: I just have the pem file which I've downloaded from aws after the creation of the docker instance..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your machine ip address to allowed host to the security group used by your ec2 instance. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

Generate a ssh key (if you didn't):

```
 ssh-keygen
```

Then install your public key in the server using **ssh-copy-id**:

```
 ssh-copy-id user@remote-server
```

Where user is your remote user and remote-server your server IP/URL.

Comment: Please read the question and the existing comments clearly. Your answer is completely wrong.